# medfilt2 filter expects input to be two-dimensional

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to apply filter `medfilt2` to an image that has salt & pepper noise.

I have tried this code:

```
img = imread('4.02.04_salt&pepper.tif');
blur = medfilt2(img,[3 3]);
imshow(blur);
```

but I got an error:

```
`Error using medfilt2
 Expected input number 1, A, to be two-dimensional.

 Error in medfilt2>parse_inputs (line 106)
 validateattributes(a, {'numeric','logical'}, {'2d','real'},
 mfilename, 'A', 1);

 Error in medfilt2 (line 48)
 [a, mn, padopt] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

 Error in codLab3 (line 87)
 blur = medfilt2(img,[3 3]);`
```

I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: So which error do you get? You have not fully printed the error message.

Comment: thank you now i forgot the firs part sorry

Comment: what's the output of `size(img)` ?

Comment: Hi @LFRC you have multiple of your questions still open without an accepted answer.When a answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 16):

Your image is a very likely a color image with RGB frames. `medfilt2` only works on 2D images of a single color. The easiest workaround is probably to apply it on each color separately.

See example:

```
% load an image
img = imread('peppers.png');

% add some noise
img_noisy = imnoise(img, 'salt & pepper', 0.02);
figure; imshow(img_noisy);

% apply medfilt2 on each color
img_filtered = img_noisy;
for c = 1 : 3
    img_filtered(:, :, c) = medfilt2(img_noisy(:, :, c), [3, 3]);
end
figure; imshow(img_filtered);
```

Looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try to convert rgb to gray (`rgb2gray`):

```
img = imread('4.02.04_salt&pepper.tif');
img = rgb2gray(img); % add this line
blur = medfilt2(img);
imshow(blur);
```